# "Bad argument syntax" with MessageFormat

Tags: java, html, messageformat

I got this `html` syntax which is filled with help of a `MessageFormat`:

```
private final String WRAPPABLE_HTML = "<html><head>"
        + "<style>div:after{text-decoration: line-through;}"
        + "</style></head>"
        + "<body style='width:{0}px;margin: 0 auto;'><div>{1}</div>{2}</body></html>";
```

if I call:

```
MessageFormat.format(
              WRAPPABLE_HTML, 200, lCat,lDog);
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad argument syntax: text-decoration: lin ...
at com.ibm.icu.text.MessagePattern.parseArg(MessagePattern.java:1106)
at com.ibm.icu.text.MessagePattern.parseMessage(MessagePattern.java:1042)
```

without the `style` section everything works fine.
Did I use any `keyword` within the `style` attributes?

Thx for your help.

Stefan

Comment: You should probably escape the curly braces inside the style tag.

Comment: ok that's it! thx a lot! If you post it as answer I'll accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the curly braces :

```
private final String WRAPPABLE_HTML = "<html><head>"
        + "<style>div:after'{'text-decoration: line-through;'{'"
                            ^                                ^
        + "</style></head>"
        + "<body style='width:{0}px;margin: 0 auto;'><div>{1}</div>{2}</body></html>";
```